How auto execute function and change stroke color to svg by percent?
I'm aproach tto js but I've many difficult to do the below action.
I’m using the circlifull jquery for a data counter in my web page, the data is calle ny api from the server and sent to the page by modifying the css. I have difficult to change the attribute stroke to class "circle" setting colors by percent printed in the text section.
Source code circlifull
<section id="connect-data" stroke="rgb(255, 0, 0)" class="svg-container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">undefined<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
<circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="36, 20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>undefined<text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">10%</text></svg>
</section>

I tried this test code inside to the html page for to change the color to circlifull progress bar but doesn't work.
<script>
// Color red     --> rgb(255, 0, 0);
// Color orange  --> rgb(255, 182, 25);
// Color green   --> rgb(0, 128, 0);
$(document).ready(function() {
  if
  document.getElementById("connect-data").setAttribute ("stroke", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
 });
</script>

How can I change the color and also setting condition for to assign:
Red under 10%
Orange 10% to 30%
Green 30%+
???
Thanks if someone can help me.

Section container
<section id="connect-data" stroke="rgb(255, 0, 0)" class="svg-container"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">undefined<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle> <circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="36, 20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>undefined<text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">10%</text></svg> </section>

My JS code
<script>
// Color red     --> rgb(255, 0, 0);
// Color orange  --> rgb(255, 182, 25);
// Color green   --> rgb(0, 128, 0);
$(document).ready(function() {
  if
  document.getElementById("connect-data").setAttribute ("stroke", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
 });
</script>


I update the progress bar every second and move closer to the maximum data of 20,000 by 1,000 per second. In the middle, I write in % where it is.
At 30% or above it is green, at 10% or above it is orange, otherwise it is red.


// Color red     --> rgb(255, 0, 0);
// Color orange  --> rgb(255, 182, 25);
// Color green   --> rgb(0, 128, 0);
$(document).ready(function() {
    let start = 0;
    const end = 20000;

    function progressBar() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            start += 1000;

            document.querySelector(".timer").innerHTML = (100 / (end / start)) + "%"; // percentage
            document.querySelector(".circle").setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", (360 / (end / start)) + ", 360"); // stroke-dasharray

            if (start >= (end * 0.3)) { // +30%
                document.querySelector(".circle").setAttribute("stroke", "rgb(0, 128, 0)"); // green
            }
            else if (start >= (end * 0.1)) { // +10%
                document.querySelector(".circle").setAttribute("stroke", "rgb(255, 182, 25)"); // orange
            }
            else {
                document.querySelector(".circle").setAttribute("stroke", "rgb(255, 0, 0)"); // red
            }

            if (start < end) {
                progressBar();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    progressBar();
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="connect-data" class="svg-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">
        <circle class="border" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#cccccc" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
        <circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="0, 360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
        <text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" style="font-size: 22px;" fill="#aaa">0%</text>
    </svg>
</section>



I hope this helps!

You can simplify the progress animation by adding a pathLength attribute value of 100. This way the stroke-dasharray values can easily
be updated relative to a range from 0–100 percent.
// 10%
stroke-dasharray="10 100"

For contextual stroke color values, add some conditions like so
  let stroke = 'green'
  if(value<=30) stroke = 'orange'
  if(value<10) stroke = 'red'



let gauge = document.querySelector('.circle')
let textProgress = document.querySelector('.timer')

// progress animation on page load
setTimeout((e) => {
  updateProgress(gauge, 20)
}, 500)

inputProgress.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  let value = +e.currentTarget.value
  updateProgress(gauge, value)
})

function updateProgress(el, value) {
  textProgress.textContent = `${value}%`

  let stroke = 'green'
  if (value <= 30) stroke = 'orange'
  if (value < 10) stroke = 'red'

  // add a tiny offset to fix gaps at 100%
  if (value === 100) value = 101
  el.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${value} 100`)
  el.setAttribute('stroke', `${stroke}`)
}
.circle {
  transition: 0.5s
}

svg {
  width: 50%
}
<p>Progress:<input id="inputProgress" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="1"></p>

<section id="connect-data" stroke="rgb(255, 0, 0)" class="svg-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
    <circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="10" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="0 100" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
    <text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">0%</text>
  </svg>
</section>



